# change the decorator parameters when running the function?

Tags: python, decorator

I wrote a decorator factory that takes input and output filenames:

```
def run_predicate(source, target):
    '''This is a decorator factory used to test whether the target file is older than the source file .'''
    import os    
    def decorator(func):
        '''This is a decorator that does the real work to check the file ages.'''
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            '''Run the function if target file is older than source file.'''
            if not os.path.exists(target) or \
               os.path.getmtime(source) > os.path.getmtime(target):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return None
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

and a decorated function:

```
@run_predicate("foo.in", "foo.out")
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b
```

This is basically set up to run `foo()` only when the input file is updated later than the output file. The problem is that I want to dynamically change the dependency, i.e. the input and out file names, according to different situations. For example, sometimes I want to run `foo()` if `"foo.in"` is newer than `"foo.out"`; other times, I want to run it only when `"spam.in"` is newer than `"spam.out"`, etc. How can I do that without changing the function definition or its decoration?

Comment: Where do you use `source` and `target`?

Comment: sorry, I had changed original code to make a simple example and forgotten to update the variable name. corrected now.

Comment: I think You can pass to decorator  not string literals but some mutable objects.

Comment: @oleg: that's actually a good idea. although the reference is bound when the decorated function is defined, by using a mutable variable, one can always change its value. thanks.